# java optional parameter error/ transfer error

Tags: java

I try to enter the following on the command line :
java class name 10 -o
but it has to work without the -o

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String a;
    if (args[1] != "-o" || args[1] == null) {
         a = "emtpy";
      }
}
public static void p(int n, String a){
```

there's always this mistake when I do it without -o: unfortunately this error always comes: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at class name.main(eratosthenes.java:4)

Comment: Instead of a null check, check the **size** of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't test `String` equality with `!=` and do check `args.length` (not for `null`).

```
if (args.length > 1 && !args[1].equals("-o")) {
    a = "empty";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The size of the args is determined after you run the java command, so it will be initialized something like this:

```
String args[1] = {"10"};
```

So, you'll have to check the size of args (`args.length`).

Also, I recommend you to always check for its size, because if you run the java command without any input args it will throw the NPE on the first line of `main` method.

Example of implementation:

```
int n;
String a;
if (args.length == 0) {
    n = 0;
    a = "empty"
} else if (args.length == 1) {
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a = "empty"
} else {
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a = args[1];
}
// other code here
p(n,a); // call the method you want
```

Of course it's not the brightest but it will work.

Also, it seems that you are a beginner with java and I recommend you to see some java guides first, before starting to debug :).

Comment: like that ? `public static void main (String[] args){
  int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  String a;
  if (args.length >=1) {
       a = "leer";
    }
    }`

Comment: Close enough, check my update with the example code. I think it's the best as it will also work for 0 input arguments (like calling `java classname`).